# How to save a kafka topic at shutdown

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm configuring my first kafka network. I can't seem to find any support on saving a configured topic. I know I can configure a topic from the [quickstart guide here](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart), but how do I save it? I thought I could add the topic info to a `.properties` file inside the `config` dir, but I don't see any support for that.

If I shutdown my machine, my topic is deleted. How do I save the configuration?

Comment: What do you mean by save a topic ? Once you create a topic, it's persisted, unless you explicitly delete it. Can you please elaborate

Comment: the topic persists until I shutdown the machine. Shouldn't there be a way (perhaps in zookeeper) to define a topic -- even without explicitly creating it through CLI

Comment: No. Why would someone want to mess with Zookeeper directly ? Kafka utilities are there to abstract these complications

Comment: so there is no way for me to configure a topic to a `.properties` file, or maybe some kafka object?

Comment: Kakfa topics are either created using the CLI utility or auto-created (if enabled) when a producer (first) pushes data to the topic. The topic itself does not get deleted unless explicitly done

Comment: Properly configured Kafka and zookeeper will not delete topics when the machine is shutdown. Are you running a virtual machine, docker, or on bare metal? What directory have you configured as your Kafka log directory? What directory is your zookeeper log directory?

Answer (score 2):

Could the topic be deleted because you are using the default broker config? With the default config, Kafka logs are stored under /tmp folder. This folder gets wiped out during a machine reboot. You could change the broker config and pick another location for Kafka logs.